# Is there any better way to do this in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know that is there any better method to do :

```
var name = $('input').attr("name") != "undefined" ? $('input').attr("name") : "";
```

Here i am reading the `name` attribute of `input`. My problem is when i read the `name` for newly created `text` element, then it was `undefined`. So for not showing `undefined` to the user i have to put this check.Now i have to ready so many properties and in all of then the same problem exist so that`s why i want to know that, Is there any better way to deal will this?

Comment: You don't appear to be specifying `input[type=text]` in your question, is that a typo?

Comment: ok i will remember this for future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Short circuit evaluation:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (I love this in JS)

```
var name = $('input').attr("name") || '';
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to explicitly compare it to undefined. undefined will return false when used in an if statement. By using OR operation you can assign empty string in that case.

```
var name = $('input').attr("name") || '';
```

Also undefined and `"undefined"` are not equal in JavaScript. Your original code would already get false negatives.